# Howto get a screenshot of Visual Studio 2015 with menu pulled down

Tags: visual-studio-2015, printscreen

I 'd like to screencapture Visual Studio 2015 with some menues pulled down. With all screencapture and bare printscreen tools I get the same: a screenshot, but none of the menu stuff is displayed. Even when menues are displayed, I hit printscreen, the menues are on the screen before and after hitting the screen, but its not on the screenshot. I It's like some menue layer is not part of the screen, it never appears on any screenshot!!

Is there are way to do this? Is there a tool, that can do that?

I'm not happy to be forced to take a photo of the screen with my digital camera, bu that's the only solution I know so far in this blunt situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `Microsoft Snipping Tool`, I also failed to capture the `Visual Studio 2015` menu. But a simple `Ctrl-Alt-PrtScr` stored the following picture in my clipboard:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I tried snipping tool before and it didn't work. With your positive prove I tried again and it works after these preconditions: 1.) stop dropbox service, to prevent it to capture the CTRL-ALT-PRINTSCREEN, before it can be caugth by the snipping tool. 2.) Start snipping tool, then ESC to exit immediate capture 3.) Pulldown the menues eg. of Visual Studio 4.) CTRL-ALT  printscreen (copies the stuff into clipboard)

Comment: Important Addition: Snipping tool must be started. Without snipping tool the menues are immediately closed when pressing CNTRL-ALT beforde you can hit PRINTSCREEN

Comment: this also works for intellisense/tooltips. Also intellisense failure tooltips on the `<note>` failure tooltip